# Align a variable in memory with offset from power of two in memory

Tags: c, gcc, linker, embedded, ld

I would like to place a 2kB chunk of memory, aligned *16 bytes before* a 1024 bytes alignment.

Platform : arm, bare metal, GNU toolchain. No need for portability

Can I do that with either GCC/attributes pragmas, `ld` custom linker script or any other solution ?

I would like to avoid wasting 1kB for that (basically placing a 3kB chunk of memory aligned at 1kB & adding 1024-16 bytes of padding). 
Forcing a particular address to place the data is possible, but will `ld` be able to place variables before and after it (or is it just a way to put padding ? )

Context : buffer needs to be at 1k boundary by hardware design , but I'd like to add a bit of room before / after to be able to copy to this buffer with no bounds checking if my source is at most 16B wide.

edit: added example.

Let's say I have RAM starting at 0x2000000. I need a `char buf[2048]` be placed in it, at 1024*N-16 offset - ie `(&buf[16])%1024==0` , hopefully without losing 1008 padding bytes.

(edit2)
So I'd like to have :

- 0x2000000 - some vars
- 0x2000010 - some other vars ...
- 0x2000100 - some other vars ...
- 0x20003F0 - char buf[2048] : here (int)&buf[16]%1024=0x2000400%1024==0
- 0x2000BF0 - some other vars ...

Comment: you could make i.e. structure of 2 buffers of size 1024. One you'll set to be aligned to 16.

Comment: You should define a specific section into your linker script, with the required aligment

Comment: @koper : I'd like them to be aligned 16 bytes ***before*** 1024. your solution IIUC, woud have 2  buffers of size 1024 aligned to 16 (so either aligned to 16,32,48,64 ... )

Comment: @LP : can you elaborate ? I'd like to create such a script but I cannot get the correct parameters / instructions that would let me declare data aligned before a power of two boundary (and not lose 1k of memory).

Comment: why the downvote ? is the question badly formulated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALIGN(exp)` is equivalent to `(. + exp - 1) & ~(exp - 1)`.  Of course, that expression only works if `exp` is a power of two.  So you can't use `ALIGN()`, but you can write your own expression that does produce the result you want.  Something like `((. + 1024 + 16 - 1) & ~(1024 - 1)) - 16` should do the trick.  Plug in various values for `.` and you see it rounds up like you want.

The problem you'll have is that the linker will place every section you specified to be before your special section before it, and every section specified to be after it after it.  It won't cleverly order the .data sections of different files to be before or after so as to produce the minimum amount of padding.  It also won't re-order individual variables within an object file and section at all.  If you are trying to pack as tightly as possible, I think you'll need to do something like:

```
.data : {
    *(.about1008bytes)
    . = ((. + 1024 + 16 - 1) & ~(1024 - 1)) - 16
    *(.DMAbuf)
    *(.data)
}
```

Use a section attribute to place your buffer in `.DMAbuf` and try to find close to but not more than 1008 bytes of other data variables and stick them in section `.about1008bytes`.

If you want to go crazy, use `gcc -fdata-sections` to place every data object in its own section, extract the section sizes with readelf, give that to a program you write to sort them for optimal packing that then spits out a chunk of linker script listing them in the optimal order.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a specific section into your linker script, with the required alignment.

Looking at [the man](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html)

> **ALIGN(exp)**
>
> Return the result of the current location counter (.) aligned to the next exp boundary. exp must be an expression whose value is a power of two. This is equivalent to

```
(. + exp - 1) & ~(exp - 1)
```

> `ALIGN` doesn't change the value of the location counter--it just does arithmetic on it. As an example, to align the output .data section to the next 0x2000 byte boundary after the preceding section and to set a variable within the section to the next 0x8000 boundary after the input sections:

```
SECTIONS{ ...
  .data ALIGN(0x2000): {
    *(.data)
    variable = ALIGN(0x8000);
  }
... }
```

> The first use of ALIGN in this example specifies the location of a section because it is used as the optional start attribute of a section definition (see section Optional Section Attributes). The second use simply defines the value of a variable. The built-in NEXT is closely related to ALIGN.

As an example you can define your section

```
SECTIONS
{
  .myBufBlock ALIGN(16) :
  {
    KEEP(*(.myBufSection))
  } > m_data
}
```

and into your code you can

```
unsigned char __attribute__((section (".myBufSection"))) buf[2048];
```

---

**EDIT**

```
SECTIONS
{
  .myBufBlock 0x0x7FBF0 :
  {
    KEEP(*(.myBufSection))
  } > m_data
}
```

and into your code you can

```
unsigned char __attribute__((section (".myBufSection"))) buf[16+2048+16];
```

To your DMA you can set the address `&buf[16]` that will be 1k aligned.

Comment: Sure, but exp must be a power of two, so should I use exp=1024 here ? what about the -16 Bytes offset then ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would like by example the buffer buf to be aligned at address N*1024-16, eg: address 1024-16=1008, or 2k-16=2032, or even 511k-16==0x7FBF0
your example would align mybufblock to N*16

Comment: There is some misunderstanding, I think. Align refers to aligmenet of data inside section. Start address of section is another matter and can be defined, e.g.: .`myBufBlock 0x123456 :`

Comment: let's say I have RAM at 0x2000000. I need a char[2048] be placed at 1024*N-16 offset within it, hopefully without losing 1008 padding bytes.

Comment: So: could you post your linker script where the 1024 alignment is defined? If so I can take a look at it and understand what you mean. Because it is very strange to have a 1024 bytes alignment in a data section.

Comment: Well, I can't understand how I would do so I did not start doing it. alignment at 1K comes from a hardware constraint (DMA must start transfers from 1k-aligned address, I would like to be able to blit a little - 16bytes- before that)

Comment: That might work ; could I place (say, .bss) variables before AND after this section ? or do I need to manually define a before and after section and send variables in either ?

Comment: bss is a section, you cannot put your own section in between.

Comment: that was my understanding, sorry I meant variables that generally should go to bss.  So that means I should define pre/post sections and assign variables manually there ...